# Clang Static Code Analyzer Output Format for Xcode project

Tags: objective-c, xcode, clang-static-analyzer

I am trying to run inbuilt Xcode Clang static analyzer on ObjectiveCProject. I want to know if it is possible to transform the Obj-C Analyzer output into a another format that sonar plugin can consume. Since there is no Sonar plugin yet for objectiveC that has full features.

Answer (score 1):

This is the command you can use to run clang for the iOS application:

```
scan-build -o static_analyzer_results xcodebuild -configuration Debug -sdk iphonesimulator
```

This creates the html reports in static_analyzer directory. Check this for reference:

http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/scan-build.html

Not sure if you can feed them into Sonar but they are well formatted.

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I have been doing with scan-build command. I can view the report results in the browser. But I am trying to find a way to feed into Sonar. Or may be through XSLT I can tranform into format that sonar plugin can consume.